# Regex for finding occurrences of all strings present in the original searched term

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm searching for string ***"longer"*** on string: **"This is a *long* sentence. But can be *longer."***

I am trying to get the range of all the words that are present in the original search term. In the above scenario, it would be the ranges of ***"long"*** and ***"longer"***. Please let me know if this is possible with regex?

The code that I'm using:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfAllRanges = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *completeString = @"This is a long sentence. But can be longer.";
NSString *searchedTerm = @"longer";
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, completeString.length);
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", searchedTerm];
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

[expression enumerateMatchesInString:completeString options:0 range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
 {
     NSRange foundRange = [result rangeAtIndex:0];
     [arrayOfAllRanges addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:foundRange]];
 }];

NSLog(@"Array of all ranges %@", arrayOfAllRanges);
```

The above code returns just the occurrences of *"longer"* with the regex *"(longer)"* but I'm looking for a replacement regex that finds the text *"long"* as well.

Comment: This is beyond the scope of regex. Regex is used to find patterns but in order to accomplish what you are asking for you would need to have a dictionary of valid words to compare against. There is no way to find sub-words (such as "long" in "longer") if you have no concept of distinct and valid words.

Comment: On the flip side, if you are searching for the term "long" it is very easy to do regex that will return both "long" and "longer"

Comment: Do you mean something as simple as `(long(er)?)` ?

Comment: Should the search also find "lo"? How about "on"? What about "er" or "ng"?

Comment: Thats a good point. Yes, if a word in the complete sentence has "on", or "er", then their range should also be returned. I did "[longer]" but that went at a character level.

Comment: But not "lo" or "ng"? Why not? How does the computer know that?

Comment: Yes, including "lo" and "ng".

Comment: So any substring of the original search term? Any substring of length >= 2?

Comment: It can be a single character as long as there's a word like that in the complete string. By word, I mean character(s) separated by spaces.

Comment: You could dynamically create a regex like longer|longe|long|lon|lo|l.  But if you want something like onger, etc., it gets a lot more complicated.